# IF UPDATE is success how to get acknowledegment whether it is sucess or failure in procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle10g, oracle11g

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Number of rows affected by an UPDATE in PL/SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/861983/number-of-rows-affected-by-an-update-in-pl-sql)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE P_Update(in_termid IN VARCHAR2,StmntType IN VARCHAR2)
AS
BEGIN
IF StmntType = 'UpdateCS'
BEGIN
update OP_TTER_MAPPING set TXN_STATUS = 'N' where  TERMINAL_ID = in_termid;
END  

Else If StmntType = 'UpdateHS' 
BEGIN
update OP_TTERMINALMASTER set TXN_STATUS = 'N' where  TERMINAL_ID =  in_termid;
END  
end P_UpdateTIDStatus;
```

1. In the above procedure if the UPDATE is success i want to know it is successful or failure, how to do that, i should get some acknowledgement, how to modify the above proc to get acknowledgement?
2. can i assign  like this set TXN_STATUS = 'N' in procedure?
3. Is this the correct way `IF StmntType = 'UpdateCS'` can i compare like this, if its correct v are going to create the procedure in backend and im going to execute from frontend, how ill i know  what the "StmntType " are

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean if UPDATE is successful or not you want to return some value?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/861983/number-of-rows-affected-by-an-update-in-pl-sql   - Duplicate question, use sql%rowcount

Answer (score 0):

sql%rowcount will give you count and if update is not successful then you need not worry, it will give you error... :P Normally people use expection of catch a error like this. Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

Try as follows, let me know if you get any compilation errors because I have not tested it.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE P_Update(in_termid IN VARCHAR2,
                          StmntType IN VARCHAR2,
                                     returnval IN OUT NUMBER)
IS 
BEGIN
 IF (StmntType = 'UpdateCS') then
         update OP_TTER_MAPPING set TXN_STATUS = 'N' 
         where  TERMINAL_ID = in_termid;
   END IF;
  returnval := 0;
 EXCEPTION
 WHEN OTHERS THEN
   returnval := 1;
   raise_application_error
      (-20140                                      
      ,'Exception is raised'
      );
END P_Update;
```

When you call your procedure from front end, you can check with return value, if it is 1 then update has failed.