# Make sure only one row is updated in PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sql-update

I have a long list of `UPDATE` statements that I run on my Oracle 11g server:

```
UPDATE Table SET Column1 = 'One' WHERE Column2 = 'Example';
UPDATE Table SET Column1 = 'Two' WHERE Column2 = 'Something';
-- ...
```

I want to check that each `UPDATE` affects exactly one row (not zero, not more than one), and if it doesn't stop the execution, raise an error, and roll back all of the updates.

I was hoping for a syntax like this perhaps:

```
UPDATE Table SET Column1 = 'One' WHERE Column2 = 'Example';
ASSERT sql%rowcount = 1;
```

That does not seem to exist, so maybe I should do something like this:

```
UPDATE Table SET Column1 = 'One' WHERE Column2 = 'Example';
IF sql%rowcount != 1 THEN
  -- Do something, but what?
END IF;
```

However, I am not sure what to put inside the `IF` statement or if that is even a good approach. So, what is the most elegant way of accomplishing this?

Comment: `RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20000,'Error');` -- ?

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/861983/number-of-rows-affected-by-an-update-in-pl-sql) similar situation, i think it will help you

Comment: If you have a unique key on "Key" then you only have to test whether any rows were updated at all.

Comment: @DavidAldridge Sorry, the choise of column name might have been a bit misleading. There are different things in the `WHERE` clauses and I can not be sure there is not more than one match.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
UPDATE your_table SET Column = 'One' WHERE Key = 'Example';
IF SQL%ROWCOUNT <> 1 THEN
  ROLLBACK;
  RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR( -20000, 'Incorrect number of rows updated for Key "Example".' )
END IF;
```

Or:

```
DECLARE
  p_rowid ROWID;
  p_key   YOUR_TABLE.KEY%TYPE := 'Example';
BEGIN
  SELECT ROWID INTO p_rowid FROM your_table WHERE Key = p_key;

  UPDATE your_table SET Column = 'One' WHERE ROWID = p_rowid;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    ROLLBACK;
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR( -20000, 'No data found for key "'|| p_key || '".' );
  WHEN TOO_MANY_ROWS THEN
    ROLLBACK;
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR( -20001, 'More than one row found for key "'|| p_key || '".' );
END;
```

Answer (score 3):

As you expect the updates to affect one row each, you could simply put the query to get that one row in a subquery, which would result in an ORA-01427 exception ("single-row subquery returns more than one row") when there is more than one.

```
UPDATE Table SET Column = 'One' WHERE ROWID = (SELECT ROWID FROM TABLE WHERE Key = 'ABC');
UPDATE Table SET Column = 'Two' WHERE ROWID = (SELECT ROWID FROM TABLE WHERE Key = 'DEF');
...
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Would this have any performance implications? Would it also ensure that all previous updates are rolled back if one fails?

Comment: Performance issues, if any, should be small, as this is about what the DBMS does internally anyhow: first find the row, then update. And yes, you are in one transaction. As long as you haven't issued a COMMIT, an exception would rollback *all* updates.

Comment: @jva: Darn it, you are right! So my answer doesn't solve the request and we are back to checking SQL%ROWCOUNT and raise an exception ourselves. Sorry Anders.

Answer (score 3):

Easy way for one statement:

```
SAVEPOINT before_my_update;

UPDATE Table 
SET Column = 'One' 
WHERE Key = 'Example';

IF sql%rowcount != 1 THEN
  ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT before_my_update;
  raise_application_error(-20000,'More than one row affected!');
END IF;
```

For all updates on table:

- create package with global variable
- in statement level before update trigger initialize it to 0
- in row level before update trigger check if it is 0.

  - if it is not 0, raise error
  - if it is 0, increment it by 1