# SELECT @@ROWCOUNT Oracle equivalent

Tags: sql, oracle, rowcount

I have an application for query management. Previously I was using SQL Server database, and to get the number of affected rows by a query I used to do:

`SELECT * FROM TABLE` (or any other select query)

and then I do `SELECT @@ROWCOUNT` to get the number of rows affected by the last executed query.

I have read about `SQL%ROWCOUNT`, but I am not able to make it work in a SELECT statement

Is there any way to do this in a Oracle database?. Thank you!

Edited:

I have solved this by doing `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (QUERY)` to get the number of rows affected by the query, I discarted this approach because it was not working in SQL Server if the query contains an `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Number of rows affected by an UPDATE in PL/SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/861983/number-of-rows-affected-by-an-update-in-pl-sql) Should work with `Insert` too

Comment: There is no exact pure SQL equivalent that I know of.  You can do this from PL/SQL, but I'm not sure it's what you'll want.  If you provide a bit more context on how you'll be executing the query and what is the reason you need the count, there may be alternatives that you can use.

Comment: Thank you @sstan, that is what I wanted to know, I did it with a workaround  doing ```SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (QUERY)```. I discarted this approach because it didn't work on SQL Server if the query contains an ORDER BY clause, but it seems to be working fine on Oracle

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know of any exact equivalent in Oracle that you can use in pure SQL.

An alternative that may work for you, depending on your specific need, is to add a `count(*) over ()` to your `select` statement to give you the total number of rows.  It would at least save you from having to re-execute the query a 2nd time.

```
select t.*,
       count(*) over () as num_rows
  from table t
 where ...
```

Or, if you can't change the original query, then you can wrap it like this:

```
select t.*,
       count(*) over () as num_rows
  from (query) t
```

Comment: I have to agree with Juan's comment above that this is a repeat of [Number of rows affected by an UPDATE in PL/SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/861983/number-of-rows-affected-by-an-update-in-pl-sql). The answer given there is a much better answer without any workarounds.