# Equivalent to SQLERRM when no error?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle12c, execute-immediate

Does anyone knows if there is an equivalent to `SQLERRM` when no error occurred?

I know I can count the affected rows like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/861983/number-of-rows-affected-by-an-update-in-pl-sql), but can I automatically get the message I would get from `SQLPLUS` e.g. `role granted.` after an `execute immediate` in PL/SQL?

I am trying to do

```
begin
  execute immediate 'grant select on s1.tbl1 to user1';
  dbms_output.put_line(<some function>);
end;
```

and get

> `Grant succeeded.`

Thanks,
J

Comment: a) `<some function>` - THere is no such function, that will provide you with the `Grant succeeded` message. b) `sql%rowcount` will not help you here. In this case, it'll be 0 anyway.  c) You can look at `sqlcode`, which if execution went smoothly would provide you with a success code `0 (ORA-0000 - normal, successful completion)`. But the latter one won't help you much either. So just use `dbms_output.put_line('Grant succeeded');`  and let any exception should it occur be propagated or logged.

Answer (score 2):

Feedback like "Grant succeeded." is the feature of sqlplus.

If you enable SQL*Net tracing (details http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/apxtblsh.htm#JJDBC28987 or http://www.juliandyke.com/Diagnostics/Trace/NetTrace.php) you will see that string "Grant succeeded" is NOT something client application sqlplus receives from Oracle.

So how does it know what to display? Because sqlplus has privimitive mechanism of checking command type before sending it to server. If you type non-existend command then it will not be even sent to server (you can check that also in SQL*NET trace).

Moreover you can check list of commands if you open binary of sqlplus as text and search for string "grant", for example (bottom left corner on screenshot).

[image]

In below case there will be no exchange with server because command is intentionally wrong.

> SQL> some_command
>
> SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "some_comma..." - rest of line
>   ignored.

So Oracle knows command type before sending SQL text to server and for some commands it receives additional information after execution. Like number of rows affected for DML. This information is enough to display "feedback".

Back to your task, the easiest way would be to implement primitive parsing of first 1-3 words of the command and display correponding message if no errors occured.

Hardcore option is to enable SQL tracing and derive command type from trace file.

```
=====================
PARSING IN CURSOR #3 len=31 dep=0 uid=91 oct=17 lid=91 tim=2178486867995 hv=3483936374 ad='b967c6a4' sqlid='10y8y7m7uj9mq'
grant execute on <...> to <...>
END OF STMT
PARSE #3:c=0,e=614,p=0,cr=0,cu=0,mis=1,r=0,dep=0,og=1,plh=0,tim=2178486867994
=====================
```

oct means Oracle Command Type

```
SQL> select command_name from v$sqlcommand where command_type = 17;

COMMAND_NAME
----------------------------------------------------------------
GRANT OBJECT
```

Another option is to enable Audit but my preference would be to keep it simple.

Answer (score 0):

If it is only the output for success message is what we are concerned, then simply using exceptions would help.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
BEGIN
  execute immediate 'grant select on s1.tbl1 to user1' ;
  dbms_output.put_line('Grant succeeded');
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('Grant Failed');
    procedure_to_log_error(SQLERRM);
END;
```

Comment: E.g. means "for example". I would like the message to be contextual after the command passed as"immediate". This doesn't answer correctly. Grant was only an example. Thank you anyway. I understand your rep-...ring behavior. I was so once but realized I came too late to SO...

Comment: What does " rep..ring behaviour"  mean?

Comment: It means you are in desperate need for reputation. But you worth better than just that, system is complete unfair. See sometimes how poor questions get so much reputation!! Like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/861983/number-of-rows-affected-by-an-update-in-pl-sql . Anyway, sorry, bad evening last night. Still not an answer.